# How to control tinyMCE convertor?

Tags: tinymce, editor, tinymce-5, tinyeditor

I am currently using @tinymce/tinymce-vue: ^4.0.7(v5.1.1).
tinymce core version is v5.

I want to set data tiny-mce.

### 1. we dont need br tag on first line and last line.

The data was set as follows

```
<blockquote>
   <p>ABCDEF<br>ABCDEF</p>
</blockquote>
```

But converted tag as follows.

```
<blockquote>
  <br>
  <p>ABCDEF</p>
  <br>  
  <br>
  <p>ABCDEF</p>
  <br>
</blockquote>
```

how can i remove too much br tags?

### 2. We don't need divide li tag.

The data was set as follows

```
const content = `<ol>
 <li>ABCD</li>
 <li>BCDE</li>
</ol>`;
```

But converted tag as follows.

```
<ol>
  <ol>
     <li>ABCD</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
<ol>
  <ol>
     <li>BCDE</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

how can i solve this problems?